# Android ndk option increases the size of my apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I'm using **ndk** because my app was not supporting in some devices but it drastically increased the **size of my binary(APK)** is there any solution to decrease the size of apk.

```
         ndk {
                  abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a","x86"
             }
```

Comment: Have you seen: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html

Comment: but is there a possibility  to upload only one apk to play store?